# How to get context in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-context

I need to run a method in onActivityResult which one of its parameters is context. I tried several ways to pass context to that method but none of them worked and the context is considered as null. Is there any way to get context in onActivityResult?

**Additional Info:**
onActivityResult is implemented in a subclass of PreferenceFragmentCompat and getActivity and getContext return null.

Comment: Please show your code in `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: use this inside onActivity Result, !!

Comment: @notTdar  onActivityResult is in a Fragment

Comment: infaltedView.getConext or getActivity or WhatEverFragment.this....

Answer (score 2):

If your `onActivityResult()` is implemented on a subclass of `Activity`, use `this`, as `Activity` is a `Context`.

If your `onActivityResult()` is implemented on a subclass of `Fragment`, use `getActivity()` to get the `Activity` that is hosting this fragment (and, again, `Activity` is a `Context`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My onActivityResult is implemented on a subclass of Fragment, and now I'm getting this exception: `activity must not be null`

Comment: Exceuse me. It's a PreferenceFragmentCompat

Comment: @Soroush: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve]. This would include the complete Java stack trace, plus your `PreferenceFragmentCompat` subclass.